# Python format, print is aligned but document written on file is warped

Tags: python

I have spent a good three hours trying to format a data table, to be written to a file. The problem is that the output--with either the % version or the (dot) format version is warped when viewed in Win Notepad. Text strings with fixed width {:<40} option end randomly.

[image: Output here]

For instance, the first text string in line 2 has two characters extra, but the next field is displaced by one space. On a lark I checked out the output as print (on a windows terminal). It was perfectly aligned

[image]

Any reason why I am getting this odd behaviour in Notepad? I could export the table through XLWT or with prettytable, but I want to get to the bottom of this. Notepad wordwrap is off. Here is the segment to output this piece to a file.

```
outlist.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print('{:^60} {:<6}\n'.format('Key concepts','Count'))
print('{:^60} {:<6}\n'.format('============','====='))
for i in range (0,20):
    print('{:<60}|{:>6}\n'.format((outlist[i][0]).encode('utf-8').strip(),\
                                 str(outlist[i][1])))
```

Comment: How are you viewing the output in windows notepad? Are you first writing to a file and viewing that file? If so, can you show the code how you are writing to the file?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: Yes please. The output file (which become rather large) has to be shared across multiple geographies/platform. So we decided to save the output in a flat file. The code is the same, the file.write has been replaced by print for this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because windows terminal use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) while Notepad does not.

> A monospaced font [...] is a font whose letters and characters each
>   occupy the same amount of horizontal space. This contrasts with
>   variable-width fonts, where the letters and spacings have different
>   widths.

You have to configure Notepad so it uses such a font, like [Lucida Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida#Lucida_Console) for exemple.

Answer (score 0):

Select a monospaced font in notepad.

Comment: Thanks @Delgan. Any suggestions how I can output this table from Python with font information? The idea is that readers/users in other geographies--with varying recourse to stackoverflow--should not get hassled by the bad formatting.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Jansen. Any suggestions how I can output this table from Python with font information? The idea is that readers/users in other geographies--with varying recourse to stackoverflow--should not get hassled by the bad formatting.

Comment: a text file cannot have font information - it is just raw text. you can either a) configure notepad to display a monospaced font or b) output your text to a format that supports fonts - there are many choices here - e.g. pdf. Alternatively output to .csv or to a spreadsheet format

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the above, use Python's csv library to output your grid of data as a csv file. Then doubleclick the output.csv, or invoke the spreadsheet program from Python, and Excel or Libreoffice will give you access to it as a fully-fledged spreadsheet. This may be a sledgehammer to crack a nut, or not.