# least complex path to extracting context phrases around *defined* key phrase(s)

Tags: python-2.7, visualization, nltk, gephi

Beyond the problem stated in [Python format, print is aligned but document written on file is warped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201323/python-format-print-is-aligned-but-document-written-on-file-is-warped/32203256#32203256): I have extracted collection.most_common keywords (words, count), but now I have to extract the context around each keyword.

The reverse engineering is not a design flaw because some human supervisors insist on seeing keywords under the hood. They will score which keywords to  keep or junk.

Once done, I have to create a network-graph around the keywords and context (NN or NP) in NodeXL, Networkx, or Gephi.

Question: in terms of complexity, which is better:

1. go via NLTK-->finder.ngram_fd.viewitems()-->Networkx or
2. use collections.most_common-->scan input text again to extract context-->Networkx?

Any guidance? Thanks.

Comment: Your post is a bit ciphered and thus I'm not sure what the ``finder.ngram_fd.viewitems()`` will have to offer in your problem since you have already extracted the most common items. Did you solve this anyway?

Comment: @Yannis: Sorry for the muddled communication. 1. Yes, I have extracted the most common items 2. Next step: I have to find the intersection word/words across all items. 3. Scan items to extract the string in which this word(s) appear. 4. create visual representation of how the word(s) have been used.

Comment: I see... Well it is not clear what the complexity of it is. I tend to believe that ``nltk`` is doing a good job when you ask it to find n-grams and by _good job_ I mean that they make good use of pythonic ways to access data.

Comment: On the other hand n-gram finding is expensive on its own. Do you know if by knowing the words produced by collections.most_common you can quickly scan the texts somehow? I mean if nltk keeps track of neighbouring tokens. Otherwise ideally you could use ``timeit`` to time both approaches and choose the best